# I want to show $Y_{n} \xrightarrow{ p} c$ ,then show that $f(Y_{n}) \xrightarrow{ p} f(c) $

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, convergence

Let $c \in \mathbb R$ . Let be a sequence of random variables . let $f:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ be continous function . if $Y_{n} \xrightarrow{ p} c$ ,then show that $f(Y_{n}) \xrightarrow{ p} f(c) $

Comment: Use the Continuous Mapping Theorem. if the function f(.) is continuous at the point c it means that exists an arbitrary and fixed $k\gt 0$ and positive number $d\to d(k)$ such that:
$$|f(Y_n)-f(c)|\ge k \Rightarrow |Y_n-c|\ge d(k)$$ That for larger enough N allows to write:
$$0\le P\left(|f(Y_n)-f(c)|\ge k\right) \le P\left(|Y_n-c|\ge d(k)\right)$$
and the upper bound goes to 0 as $n\to0$.

Comment: I believe that the question is asking you to prove the [convergence in probability version of the continuous mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_probability).